# how to convert wchar[260] and wchar_t to const char *

Tags: c++

This code should check if specified process is running, but it fails on call of stricmp, where both parameters require const char *. How to convert variable processName and member of structure entry.szExeFile (which is wchar[260]) to const char * ?

```
 bool IsProcessRunning(wchar_t processName)

{ bool exists = false;


    PROCESSENTRY32 entry;
    entry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

    HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);

    if (Process32First(snapshot, &entry))
        while (Process32Next(snapshot, &entry)){
            if (stricmp(entry.szExeFile, processName) == 0){
                exists = true;

                CloseHandle(snapshot);
                return exists;
            }
        }
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    if (IsProcessRunning(argv[0])) { cout << "Process " << argv[0] << "is running"; }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235631.aspx

Comment: Are you intentionally using the case-insensitive variant? And are you intentionally using `wchar_t` to support non-English characters? Do you expect `"ß"` and `"SS"` to compare equal?

Comment: I just can not get wcsicmp running, do you know header file which defines it ? I do not need to use non english character, so which datatype would be sufficient ?

Comment: @JanBohac: The usual, `<string.h>`. If you stick to English, `_wcsicmp` works. (Mind the underscore! Not a standard function)

Answer (score 1):

Instead convert between wchar and char, why you do not use wcsicmp function to compare both string. Make sure both parameters (entry.szExeFile, processName) are LPCWSTR.
Even better why do not use [secure functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/k59z8dwe.aspx) to compare in a secure way.

Comment: Why not those "secure" functions? Because they're Microsoft proprietary, and try to fix the insecurity caused by outdated C string interfaces. C++ has a true string type.

Comment: @MSalters the code in the question is over Windows, thus I tried to suit my response to that environment with minimal changes (modifying just a function stricmp for _wcsicmp) . But yes, C++ has a true string type and it is always better solution.

Answer (score 0):

As you see, you already use WIN API, so you can try [`MultiByteToWideChar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

---

```
char* Convert (const std::wstring &data)
{
    if (data.empty()) 
        return "";

    int iLn = WideCharToMultiByte (CP_UTF8, 0, const_cast<LPWSTR> (data.c_str()), static_cast<int>(data.length()), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if( iLn == 0 )
    {
        return "";
    }

    std::string result (iLn, 0);
    WideCharToMultiByte (CP_UTF8, 0, data.c_str(), static_cast<int>(data.length()), const_cast<LPSTR> (result.c_str ()), iLn, NULL, NULL);

    return result.c_str();
}
```

Comment: should be sufficient to cast entry.szExeFile and processName to const char * ? Is it possible solution